# Azure pipeline : When and how to do end to end testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-devops, end-to-end

I have a react project and all the backend stuff is hosted as docker images.
I understand most of what azure pipelines are and i have set up a initial pipeline which does the following.
Installs nodes
Installs packages
Runs unit tests
Finalises and builds the project
Then publishes the artefact

This then continues to the release branch to deliver the artefact.

My question is, how and where would end to end testing fit in? Would it be in the initial pipeline or the release pipeline, additionally, how would this be done?. My confusion is that my application relies on a database, however if its running in a pipeline it will not have access to this. Using either puppeteer, or any other end to end testing library, I'm i meant to mimic a database, or can I run my docker instance within the pipeline for my backend services? If im completely missing the mark, please let me know as well.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093496/14473939

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862816/14473939

I'm no expert, but after reading a bit, it seems having a staging database (i.e. a permanently deployed backend for testing?) that is up to date with production database could be an option.